# SQL comparing strings from two tables with different data formats

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables, with different columns that I would like to compare. There is an issue in our system with serial numbers, and I want to make sure that all of the serial numbers (`CMMTTEXT` - in comma delimitted form) in **Table B** are being transferred to **Table A** (`SERLTNUM` - where each individual serial number has its own line)

Basically, what I would like to try and do is take the `SOPNUMBER`'s from the last 3 months (which I would get from **Table C**), then get all rows from **Table B** and **Table A** with the last 3 months `SOPNUMBER`'s and then somehow to make sure all serial numbers in `CMMTTEXT` in **Table B** are in **Table A** as `SERLTNUM`.

I know how to get all of the data, but I'm not sure **what I can do in order to compare the two columns in SQL when they have different data formats**. I am trying to think if there is someway I can just use `substr()` to search `CMMTTXT` but don't know how I could then display rows where there was no match found.

The `LNITMSEQ` table is an ID that corresponds to different line items in an order.

### Table A

```
+-----------+----------+----------+---------------+
| SOPNUMBER | LNITMSEQ | SERLTNUM | ITEMNMBR      |
+-----------+----------+----------+---------------+
| I327478   | 16384    | ABC123   | someItem      |
+-----------+----------+----------+---------------+
| I327478   | 32768    | DEF123   | someOtherItem |
+-----------+----------+----------+---------------+
```

### Table B

```
+-----------+----------+-----------------------------+
| SOPNUMBER | LNITMSEQ | CMMTTEXT                    |
+-----------+----------+-----------------------------+
| I327478   | 16384    | ABC123,ABC124,ABC125,ABC126 |
+-----------+----------+-----------------------------+
| I327478   | 32768    | DEF123,DEF124,DEF125,DEF126 |
+-----------+----------+-----------------------------+
```

### Table C

```
+-----------+-----------+
| SOPNUMBER | DATE      |
+-----------+-----------+
| I327478   | 5/20/2017 |
+-----------+-----------+
| I327479   | 5/21/2017 |
+-----------+-----------+
```

Comment: can you please paste your query so far?

Comment: You will need to separate the CMTTEXT in table B into rows split by comma, held in line with the SOPNUMBER - you can then test each of the CMTTEXT values individually.

Comment: you will need a variation of the following to break your comma separated string into rows: - SELECT SOPNUMBER, LNITMSEQ,
 PARSENAME(REPLACE(Split.a.value(',', 'VARCHAR(max)'),'-','.'),1) 'CMMTTEXT' 
 FROM  
 (
 SELECT SOPNUMBER, LNITMSEQ,
 CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE([CMMTTEXT], ',', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS Data 
 FROM   [table b] 
 ) AS A 
 CROSS APPLY Data.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a) - You can then use the resulting table to join on a 3 part key from table A on SOPNUMBER, LNITMSEQ, CMMTEXT

Answer (score 0):

I have commented above, but a clearer answer can be found here for what you need:

[SQL split values to multiple rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17942508/sql-split-values-to-multiple-rows)

Answer (score 0):

You can use FIND_IN_SET function like as follows

```
SELECT * FROM TableA INNER JOIN TAableB
ON FIND_IN_SET(TableA.SERLTNUM, TableB.CMMTTEXT) > 0
```

FIND_IN_SET function returns a value in the range of 1 to N if the string str is in the string list strlist consisting of N substrings. for more detail see the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)